# Nuxt 3: Generate dynamic routes from server/api when the ID is several levels deep?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying (and failing) to figure out how to generate dynamic routes based on the `MyPlaylistsData.me.spotify.playlistsConnection.nodes.id`s.

I've already taken a look at the Nuxt 3 docs for `useFetch` and `$fetch`.

Would someone please help me out?

Here's an abbreviated data structure for `/api/server/playlists`:

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "MyPlaylistsData": {
        "me": {
            "id": "me",
            "spotify": {
                "playlistsConnection": {
                    "nodes": [
                        {
                            "id": "6JjoQq2HElWYjkRbI7a25Z",
                            "name": "Playlist 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "4R1JO5cXxSJ50Dbh70qzju",
                            "name": "Playlist 2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`/pages/playlists/[id.vue]`:

```js
<template>
    <div>
        A single playlist page.
        <h2 v-html="list.name" />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const route = useRoute();
    const { data: list } = useFetch(`/api/playlists/${route.params.id}`);
</script>
```

`/server/api/playlists.js`:

```js
export default async (req, res) => {
    const playlists = await $fetch(
        `https://playlists.app/api/${process.env.PLAYLISTS_API}`
    );
  const list = playlists.MyPlaylistsData.me.spotify.playlistsConnection.nodes;

// Returns first ID, but needs to be dynamic
// const id = list.node[0].id

    if (!id) {
      return {
        playlists
      }
    } else {
    //  return dynamic single ID route – What goes here?
    }
    
}
```

Comment: So, what is not working? What do you see in your network tab?

Comment: Please do not post code snippets in comments, rather edit your question.

Comment: The /server/api/playlists.js portion has been updated. My trouble is with the JS part.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question right (if not, please rephrase), you should rename your
`/server/api/playlists.js`
to
`/server/api/[id].js`.

Then you can access this `id` in javascript like this:

```js
// /server/api/[id].js

export default async (event) => {
  const id = event.context.params.id

  // Do what you need to do with the id
  // e.g.
  const playlists = await $fetch(
        `https://playlists.app/api/${process.env.PLAYLISTS_API}`
    );
  const list = playlists.MyPlaylistsData.me.spotify.playlistsConnection.nodes;

  return list[id]
}
```

If you are using legacy handlers with `req`/`res`, your id is in `req.context.params.id`.

You'll find the documentation here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/server-routes
You might also want to check whether you don't want to use Typescript instead of Javascript. Should give you a better developer experience:

```js
// /server/api/[id].ts

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const id = event.context.params.id

  // Do what you need to do with the id

  return { hereIs: 'your data' }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the folder structure and rename some stuff and you are good.

rename/move: /server/api/playlists.js -> /server/api/playlists/index.js

and create a new file at:
/server/api/playlists/[id].js
with the same structure as index.js but handling the else case

so for example:

```js
// server/api/playlists/index.js or .ts
export default defineEventHandler( async (event) => {
  console.log("params", event.context.params)
  console.log('New request: ' + event.node.req.url)

 const playlists = await $fetch(
        `https://playlists.app/api/${process.env.PLAYLISTS_API}`
    );
  const list = playlists.MyPlaylistsData.me.spotify.playlistsConnection.nodes;

       return playlists
})
```

and

```js
// server/api/playlists/[id].js or .ts
export default defineEventHandler( async (event) => {
  console.log("params", event.context.params)
  console.log('New request: ' + event.node.req.url)
  // your else case 
})
```